# Spring @Predestroy method and context availability

Tags: spring

Do I correctly understand that when the @Predestroy method is invoked for a Spring component all other components (autowired dependencies) are still fully available in the context and not destroyed?

Thus can I invoke in the @Predestroy method other beans and not get exceptions?
I need @Predestroy to make some operations with DB through some autowired @Service bean.

Comment: No, when the Spring context shuts down, then the lifecycle of all the Spring Beans come to an end and then before the Bean xy is ultimately destroyed this very method annotated with `@PreDestroy` is executed. You are using this e.g. to save data or to clean something up - e.g. cleaning/dropping a temporary table in a database.

Comment: And how can I make DB cleaning if you say that other beans (services, data sources) may be not available?

Comment: Naturally, the other beans stay intact until @PreDestroy was executed, but then all the Spring Beans are gonna be killed.